# Sincronizar librerías necesarias de un proyecto (jar) y trabajar con GitHub

Tags: java, git, github

Estoy empezando a trabajar con GitHub y acabo de subir mi primer repositorio pero me surge esta duda. Tengo algunas librerías en archivos .jar. Cuando trabajo en netbeans al compilar estas se agregan automáticamente pero ¿Como se trabaja en github? De manera que pueda seguir utilizando las librerías y a la vez clonar el repositorio sin problemas.

Comment: No se mucho de Java pero me parece que lo que necesitas es ignorar algunos archivos que han sido compilados. Si ese es el caso, entonces lo que necesitarías es usar el archivo `.gitignore`

Comment: Cual es la forma en la que estas trabajando con GitHub?. Te hago esta pregunta porque pueden darse varios escenarios, directamente desde el IDE como IntellijIDEA, usando el GitHUb desktop para clonar los repositorios y luego trabajar con tu IDE, o simplemente descargas el repositorio desde la página y luego haces un commit con los cambios en ella mismo. Saludos.

Comment: Lo que no quiero es tener que agregar las librerias cada vez que se clone el proyecto. Pero no se si esto sea posible. Intentare primero que se suban con .gitignore y luego haber que me dice.

Comment: @Rostan Apenas estoy empezando con gitHub. No pude configurar netbeans. Por algúna razón no inicia seción en git. Instale SourceTree para el manejo.

Comment: intentastes realizar un .gitignore para tus archivos

Comment: @JackNavaRow lo intentare. Antes simulaba esto sincronizando archivos con Mega y cada vez que me cambiaba de equipo tenia que actualizar las librerias por que me daba error. Quiero evitar eso pero hasta no llegar a casa no sabre si funciona y si no funciona dia perdido XS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github (o cualquier otro sistema de control de versiones) NO es la herramienta para tratar con dependencias. De hecho no se debería incluir allí nada que sea "generado" (.class, .jar, .war), etc<sup>1</sup>.

Para desarrollos internos, en ocasiones la opción era hacer que todos los desarrolladores pusieran las librerías en la misma ubicación de su máquina. Obviamente no era muy cómodo, y resultaría inmanejable para una desarrollo opensource o incluso un departamento de desarrollo grande.

La mejor solución es usar una herramienta de gestión de dependencias, como puedan ser Maven (que parece lo más utilizado), Graddle o Ivy (esta última integrada con Ant). Tú indicas en tu fichero que tu proyecto depende de tal y tal librería, con las versiones indicadas, y el gestor de dependencias te las descarga, incluye en el empaquetado, etc.

Los inconvenientes son dos:

- Obviamente, tienes que aprender a usar la herramienta. Maven es más que un gestor de dependencias y se encarga de todo el build, pero puede ser complicado adaptar problemas que no sigan su filosofía. Ant + Ivy es más flexible, pero tienes que "programar en XML" todo lo que quieres que se haga durante el build.
- Si quieres gestionar las librerías propias (que tú o tu equipo producís), deberías montarte un repositorio para ellas, lo cual es una complicación adicional.

---

<sup>1</sup> Como cada vez que hagas un build volverás a crear todos esos archivos, subirlos implicaría a) una cantidad de cambios enormes y b) una "fiesta" continúa de conflictos con los commits de otros desarrolladores.

Comment: ok. Voy entendiendo el concepto. Pero las librerías ya estan compiladas. No las modifico y no se vuelven a subir por tanto. ¿Convendria de esta manera subirlas para trabajar?. Son parte del desarrollo y me gustaría que estuvieran disponibles. No quiero complicar el proyecto. Tienes alguna recomendación de como trabajar estos detalles? De echo solo son tres librerías.

Comment: ¿Estamos hablando de librerías de terceras partes (v.g. log4j) que usas en tu proyecto o de librerías que tú has compilado y que usas en otro proyecto?

Comment: Terceras partes.

Comment: Esas librerías no las subes, están en repositorios públicos (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core). Por ejemplo con Maven, tú en tu fichero de configuración (`pom.xml`) solo dices que quieres (tienes una "dependency") el "artefacto" `log4j-core", del grupo "org.apache.logging.log4j", versiones de tal a cual y la herramienta te descarga el jar y te lo mete en el .war, .ear, te lo copia a la carpeta que quieras, etc...

Comment: Muy bien. Esa era mi duda. Solo que en vez de utilizar maven voy a utilizar mega. Sincronizare las librerias de manera que esten disponibles en los equipos pero trabajare con GitHub para cada máquina subiendo los debidos commits ignorando las propiedades del proyecto de netbeans. En mi caso creo que será más que suficiente. Tendre disponibles las librerias pero ya no tendre que estarlas configurando cada vez o eso espero . Gracias.

Comment: si son librerias de terceros es un proyecto git con esas librerias; eso indica que tienes dos proyectos 1. el que estas programando 2. la dependencia externa que tienes (puede ser un jar), en el proyecto 1 le colocas un git ignore a el jar y el 2 lo descargas en la ruta que lo deseas

Answer (score 1):

Dale, yo no domino el tema, pero se algo. En mi caso uso 2 formas, trabajando con IntellIJ como IDE, es muy sencillo de configurar, con ello haces los commits y push directamente al repositorio y tienes consigo el CSV (control de versiones). Y la segunda es usando el [desktop de GitHub](https://desktop.github.com/), clonas el repositorio en tu máquina y luego abres el proyecto directamente desde ahí, es sencillo pero pierde su gracia ya que tendrías que el control de versión radica en el, y no el IDE (cosa novedosa). Ahora dime cual usarás y puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Pues en lugar de desktop github estoy utlizando sourcetree por que netbeans me esta dando algúnos problemas. Pero creo que la pregunta es más bien sobre gitignore de manera que el repositorio suba las librerias en jar y estas a su vez se descarguen cuando clone el repositorio.